# Strange error in Android app

Tags: android, image, android-intent, view, photo

I am taking photos via Intent. In certain phones like Samsung with around 750 mb RAM, the app suddenly closes after taking the pic. When I saw the event in logcat, it  was showing following:

```
ViewRootImpl #2 Surface is not valid
```

What do this mean and how do I correct it. This error is not happening in other phones I tested and this is specific to taking pics via intent only. Because, I am also taking videos in that Samsung phone, and it worked flawlessly. 
The scenario is:
My app started->I press a button to take a pic->Pic is captured.->Pic is said to be saved->   Now instead of displaying the gallery, the app just closes off without any notice and also there is a noticeable lag between taking pic and saving it.

Note: Pic is saved to internal storage via EXTRA_OUTPUT intent given to it.

Comment: Maybe the activity is destroyed after you took a picture (because changes its orientation), did you try to add the following line to your manifest file: `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` ?

Comment: Nope, I have used portrait mode in my application. From what I know, it seems that the phone takes pic in landscape mode. So is it possible that, while changing from landscape to portrait, it is crashing. If yes, then what would be the best method to correct it.

Comment: Try to add the mentioned line to your manifest and test is out

Comment: Did it help? If yes, I will transfer my comment to an answer, otherwise we should continue searching the solution.

Comment: @cylon Yes it helped. Thank You.

Comment: I have added my comment as an answer, feel free to accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The activity destroys itself after you took a picture in several devices (because changes its orientation), try to add the following line to your manifest file:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```